# In which direction do I unscrew this utility sink faucet to replace the washers?

Tags: plumbing, leak, screws, sink

This utility sink has a slow drip from the end of the spout. This should be easily fixed by replacing the rubber washers in the levers, however the phillips screws, shown further below, seem very tight. 
Would both screws loosen counter-clockwise, or would they be opposite? I was thinking of using a manual impact wrench (the kind you actually hit with a hammer) but I didn't want to break it in the wrong direction.

[image: Utility Sink]

[image: Utility Sink Hot Handle]

**Update:** I've removed the phillips screws, but now the part under the handle that I need to remove, indicated by the red arrow below (what's the name?) seems very stuck. Are these also both loosened counter-clockwise?

[image: Utility Sink underneath hot handle]

Bonus question: Sometimes the faucet leaks near the base of the spout (see red arrow below). Is that also fixed with a rubber seal replacement? Is that done by turning the hex ring near the arrow counter-clockwise? It's not easy to get a tool around it!

[image: Utility Sink Faucet Leak]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those screws loosen counterclockwise. Spray some WD-40 on them and let it soak in for a bit.  There is a washer or "o" ring at the base of the spout or in the base of the valve. hit that big nut with some WD-40 and turn it counterclockwise too loosen. you might have to loosen the supply nuts to get an adjustable wrench in there, a pair of Channellocks would just eat the nut up.

Comment: I was able to remove the phillips screws, but the part beneath the handle is even more stuck (see new image). Do those also both loosen counter-clockwise?

Comment: Yes they do... good luck

Answer (score 2):

In addition to JACK's answer that both the screws on the handles and the [nut] things underneath loosen counter clockwise...

The screw that actually holds the rubber washer on actually loosens *clockwise* (reverse-thread)...At least the one for the hot water anyway. I still have to replace the cold side. See photos below for image of screw mentioned.

Before replacing washer:
[image: Sink rubber washer old]

After replacing washer:
[image: Sink rubber washer replaced]

Comment: Great job.. you're moving right along....